# No lttng save/load command available

Tags: lttng

I am trying to save and load xml sesssion configuration using the lttng save/load commands but for some reason couldn't find them on "LTTng Trace Control 2.4.0" version. Does anyone know what version of lttng these commands are available from? Or do I have to compile lttng in a certain way to get this feature?

See below the result of running lttng --help. I see no save or load command.

Thank you.

**lttng --help**

LTTng Trace Control 2.4.0 - Époque Opaque

usage: lttng [OPTIONS]  []

Options:

-V, --version              Show version

-h, --help                 Show this help

```
  --list-options         Simple listing of lttng options

  --list-commands        Simple listing of lttng commands
```

-v, --verbose              Increase verbosity

-q, --quiet                Quiet mode

-g, --group NAME           Unix tracing group name. (default: tracing)

-n, --no-sessiond          Don't spawn a session daemon

```
  --sessiond-path PATH   Session daemon full path

  --relayd-path PATH     Relayd daemon full path
```

Commands:

```
add-context       Add context to event and/or channel

calibrate         Quantify LTTng overhead

create            Create tracing session

destroy           Tear down tracing session

enable-channel    Enable tracing channel

enable-event      Enable tracing event

disable-channel   Disable tracing channel

disable-event     Disable tracing event

list              List possible tracing options

set-session       Set current session name

snapshot          Snapshot buffers of current session name

start             Start tracing

stop              Stop tracing

version           Show version information

view              Start trace viewer
```

Each command also has its own -h, --help option.

Please see the lttng(1) man page for full documentation.
See http://lttng.org for updates, bug reports and news.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to get a later version.
According to the documentation for v2.6:

> To save a given tracing session configuration, do:
>   lttng save my-session
>
> To load a tracing session, simply do:
>   lttng load my-session

http://lttng.org/docs/#doc-saving-loading-tracing-session

Might not have been a feature in 2.4.

Answer (score 0):

*Save and restore* was [introduced in LTTng 2.5](http://lttng.org/docs/v2.5/#doc-whats-new).